# How linux kernel (used in Ubuntu) manages concurrent access to the data?

Tags: sync, lock

I want to know how linux kernel used in Ubuntu manages concurrent access to shared data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before version 2.6, Linux was a [nonpreemptive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29) kernel. Now, it is fully preemptive, so a task can be preempted when it is running in the kernel.

The Linux kernel provides [spinlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) and [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) for locking in the kernel. On SMP machines the fundamental locking mechanism is a [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), and the kernel is designed so that the [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock) is held only for short durations.

This is not appropriate for single-processor machines. In single-processor machines, the kernel disables kernel [preemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29); and rather than releasing the [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), it eneables kernel [preemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29).

Answer (score 0):

Sir, I think you have a misconception about what locking is, and what mutex is for. Also, you have a misconception about what Ubuntu is.

Let's start with the latter: Ubuntu is a Linux-based *distribution*. Any and all low level system architecture components are done by the Linux kernel. Ubuntu is just a way of putting different software pieces together, configuring, installing and updating them in a robust, uniform and user-friendly fashion. Your question, thus, refers to Linux, and not Ubuntu.

Mutexes are used to make sure that common resources (such as memory) are not by mistake accessed and modified at the same time. Since processes in general do not share such resources as memory (neither in Windows nor in Linux), the problem arises when one uses *threads*, and not processes. This is done using mutexes, you are right in that; [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html) you will find some more informations about that. Linux uses POSIX threads. However, whether you -- as a programmer -- use mutexes or something else (like spinlocks or critical section), that depends on you, not on the system (see [here](http://www.alexonlinux.com/pthread-mutex-vs-pthread-spinlock)), be that Windows or Linux.

As for processes, one needs file locking, but that is a different story. And yes, processes are implemented differently in Windows and in Linux (most importantly, in scheduling; see [this](http://www.engr.colostate.edu/~dilumb/Documents/CS204/05-Process-Windows_Linux_print.pdf) presentation to shed some light on that).

Comment: Yep, I do know everything. I used Ubuntu instead of linux, because Ubuntu also has its own kernel team. And I'm asking about how does linux manage concurrent access by different processes to the shared data. I'll edit the question.